# Text box data is not submitted when hitting ENTER, but works on SUBMIT button (Rails/Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Rails 4 and Bootstrap 3.  I have a simple email address box on my page (located at localhost:3000).  Clicking the SUBMIT button sends the email address to the database (MongoDB); however, hitting the ENTER key just sends the page to a localhost:3000/? url and does not submit the data to the DB.  Thanks for your help.
Here is my code:

HAML page:

```
%form#emailtextbox{role: "form"}
.form-group
    %input.form-control{placeholder: "Email address", type: "email", id: "emailbox"}/

%button.btn.btn-primary#btnSignup Submit!
```

Javascript:

```
$('#emailbox').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        SendSignup();
});

$('#btnSignup').on('click', function(){
    SendSignup();
});
```

Comment: What does SendSignup() do? Does it even run when pressing the submit button?

Comment: SendSignup() is a separate function that when called grabs the text in the box (email address) and sends to my DB.  Yes, the submit button works, just not when the Enter key is pressed.  Thanks.

Comment: call e.preventDefault() in your keyup() and it should be fine...

Comment: Hi Dan.  Thanks for trying to help.  When I use e.preventDefault(), it automatically submits the data upon hitting the first key, i.e., if I push "f" to start an email address, it triggers the submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit enter your form is being submitted.  You need to intercept that action or prevent it completely.

```
$('#yourformid').submit(function (e) {
    SendSignup();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I would also recommend against using the following code completely.  It is not needed because pressing enter will submit the form anyway, at which point the submit function will intercept the event.

```
$('#emailbox').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        SendSignup();
});
```

*************** Alternative Method ****************

```
$('#emailbox').submit(function() {
    $('#btnSignup').trigger("click");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi Raenix, thanks for trying.  I did this and it did not work:         `$('#emailbox').submit(function (e) {
     SendSignup();
     e.preventDefault();
 });`  Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: Was this form dynamically added by any chance?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I just grabbed the code from Bootstrap's documentation and added it to my page.  Thanks again.

Comment: What I mean by dynamically is did the form get injected into the screen by a user action? If it is present from page load then that isn't the issue.

Comment: I just noticed your alternative method - it didn't work either.  Just redirected to localhost:3000/? and didn't submit the email address to the DB.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: Gotcha.  No, it wasn't dynamically added.  Thanks.  It must be some quirk w/ Bootstrap.  I will probably strip the form out and use a normal, non-Bootstrap text box.